# Fastest way to initialize vector<vector<double>> with size 0 with fixed capacity

Tags: c++, vector

What is the fastest way to do:

```
template<typename T>
vector<vector<T>> vec_vec_init(T dummy_for_type, size_t outer_dim, size_t inner_dim) {

    vector<vector<T>> v(outer_dim);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < outer_dim; i++)
        v[i].reserve(inner_dim);
    return v;
}
```

i.e. if I have

```
vector<vector<double>> v = vec_vec_init((double)0, 5, 10);
```

Then, `v` vector of size 5 and each `v[i]` is empty double vector with capacity 10.

Comment: Did you have some issues with `vec_vec_init` and want them to be fixed; or you just want some other "fastest" ways to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for particular combinations of `outer_dim` and `inner_dim`?

Comment: This works fine, but I just wondered if there is any faster way for curiosity.

Comment: Usually, `outer_dim` is very large and `inner_dim` is quite small. For example, `outer_dim=1.e07` and `inner_dim=10`.

Comment: on what compiler version platform?   "fastest" isn't really a thing c++ defines.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with the C++. I just using visual Studio community 2015 on windows 10.

Comment: If its fixed size why not use `std::array`? It needs no heap allocations, has better locality of reference and will shout at you if you insert too many elements.

Comment: Also try to get rid of the vector of vectors (is it a matrix by chance?) and handle the Nth dimension by indexing of wrapper class. This makes the interface of your object a lot cleaner and readable.

Comment: I wanted to use it for the sparse matrix construction. Outter dimension coincide with the number of rows and inner dimension coincide with the number of nonzero of each row and I have prior guess for the number of nonzero. Gathering information by using loop and then sorting each row to make compressed sparse matrix. Since I'm on the starting point for my own library, I'm openned for all the possibility. I will consider your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible to give a guarantee of "fastest", but I'd probably do something like this (assuming C++11 or later)

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T> > vec_vec_init(std::size_t outer_dim, std::size_t inner_dim)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T> > v(std::vector<T>(0), outer_dim);
    for (auto &i : v) i.reserve(inner_dim);
    return v;
}
```

Notes;

- I added `std::` prefixes to those things in namespace `std`, since a template function like this will probably be defined in a header file.   There are numerous explanations (on SO, and elsewhere, easily findable using google) explaining why `using namespace std;` is a bad idea in a header file.
- This uses iterators, which have potential (not guaranteed, but often a fair bet) to give better performance than array indexing on standard containers.  Subjectively, a lot of programmers (at least, once they get the hang of using iterators) also find iterators easier to work with than array indexing as well.
- I've removed the `dummy_for_type` argument, as I consider a call like `v = vec_vec_init<Something>(outer, inner)` clearer than `v = vec_vec_init(Something(0), outer, inner)` or (if `Something` cannot be initialised to `0`) `vec_vec_init(dummy_Something, outer, inner)`.

Before C++11, I wouldn't bother using a function like this, since it will return by value.   Copying a vector by value is guaranteed to preserve size (unless the copying fails, and an exception is thrown) but not guaranteed to preserve capacity.  That applies to inner vectors in this case as well.

So I'd probably do away with the function entirely simply do this

```
std::vector<std::vector<Something> > v(outer);
for (auto &i : v) i.reserve(inner);
```

or (if I require the code to work before C++11)

```
std::vector<std::vector<Something> > v(outer);
std::vector<std::vector<Something> >::iterator i = v.begin(), end = v.end();
while (i != end)
{
     i->reserve(inner);
     ++i;
}
```

Comment: Ooh!  Your point about "will return by value .. copying is not guaranteed to preserve capacity ... this applies to inner vectors" is an *excellent* one (and should be much more prominent).  In *practise*, compilers will apply NRVO and elide the copy, but I have a nasty feeling that a C++14 compiler *could* still use a copy constructor for the return - which would destroy the reserve.  If the calling code relies on push_back not invalidating iterators, that will affect correctness - not just performance.

Comment: I did qualify that comment with "Before C++11"  for various reasons (e.g. `std::vector` having a move constructor, and "quality of implementation" concerns related to NVRO typically being more "efficient" than invoking a move constructor).  So I'd hesitate to suggest that comment applies to C++11 and later.   Doing without the function `vec_vec_init()` entirely (and implementing the loop directly) will always work as intended (at least, until some operation resizes the outer container, and invalidates iterators).

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is almost as good as it gets.  You could tweak it as:

```
template<typename T>
vector<vector<T>> vec_vec_init(T dummy, size_t outer_dim, size_t inner_dim) {

    vector<vector<T>> v(outer_dim);

    for (auto &inner: v)
        inner.reserve(inner_dim);
    return v;
}
```

It *feels* like:

```
vector<vector<T>> vec_vec_init(T dummy, size_t outer_dim, size_t inner_dim) {

    vector<T> reserved;
    reserved.reserve(inner_dim);    

    vector<vector<T>> v(outer_dim, reserved);
    return v;
}
```

ought to work (it creates `v` with `outer_dim` copies of `reserved`).  The trouble is that the copy constructor of `std::vector` does *not* (necessarily) preserve capacity.  So all you are guaranteed is that you get `outer_dim` empty vectors.

Incidentally, I would remove `dummy_for_size` from the calling sequence, and call as

```
auto vv = vec_vec_init<float>( 100*1000, 10 );
```

Comment: Does your second solution work on any platform? That would render the swap-to-fit trick pretty much useless.

Comment: @MikeMB: Not as far as I know.  swap_to_fit still works if you do it as `{declvar(v) temp{v.cbegin(), v.cend()}; using std::swap; swap(temp,v);}` - except that if you have access to `declvar`, you also have access to `v.shrink_to_fit()`.

Comment: @I also prefer shrink_to_fit. My argument was more like: "As the simple swap to fit idiom worked in the past I'd be surprised if copying would also copy capacity on common platforms"